# unable to install nvidia drivers on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nvidia, display, sony

I am trying to install Nvidia drivers on sony vaio E series with nvidia GEforce
When I try to instal additional drivers its coming like unable to download . for more options see `/var/log/jockey.log` like this...can any one help me out.

Comment: What model of graphics card do you have?

Comment: as Bruno said, please post the terminal output of this command: lspci | grep -i 'GeForce'

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found the issue was with the installer GUI. Try to install it via a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

That may work.